# Pyspark Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory

I am solving a problem using spark running in my local machine.

I am reading a parquet file from the local disk and storing it to the dataframe.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .config("spark.driver.memory","4g")\
    .config("spark.executor.memory","4g")\
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize","2g")\
    .getOrCreate()

content = spark.read.parquet('./files/file')
```

So, **Content** Dataframe contents around 500k rows i.e.

```
+-----------+----------+
|EMPLOYEE_ID|MANAGER_ID|
+-----------+----------+
|        100|         0|
|        101|       100|
|        102|       100|
|        103|       100|
|        104|       100|
|        105|       100|
|        106|       101|
|        101|       101|
|        101|       101|
|        101|       101|
|        101|       102|
|        101|       102|
       .           .
       .           .
       .           .
```

I write this code to provide each EMPLOYEE_ID an **EMPLOYEE_LEVEL** according to their hierarchy.

```
# Assign EMPLOYEE_LEVEL 1 WHEN MANAGER_ID is 0 ELSE NULL
content_df = content.withColumn("EMPLOYEE_LEVEL", when(col("MANAGER_ID") == 0, 1).otherwise(lit('')))

level_df = content_df.select("*").filter("Level = 1")

level = 1
while True:
    ldf = level_df
    temp_df = content_df.join(
        ldf,
        ((ldf["EMPLOYEE_LEVEL"] == level) & 
         (ldf["EMPLOYEE_ID"] == content_df["MANAGER_ID"])),
        "left") \
    .withColumn("EMPLOYEE_LEVEL",ldf["EMPLOYEE_LEVEL"]+1)\
    .select("EMPLOYEE_ID","MANAGER_ID","EMPLOYEE_LEVEL")\
    .filter("EMPLOYEE_LEVEL IS NOT NULL")\
    .distinct()
    
    if temp_df.count() == 0:
        break
    level_df = level_df.union(temp_df)
    level += 1
```

It's running, but very slow execution and after some period of time it gives this error.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o383.count.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.$colon$colon(List.scala:117)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.$plus$colon(List.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.String2TrimExpression.children(stringExpressions.scala:816)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.String2TrimExpression.children$(stringExpressions.scala:816)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.StringTrim.children(stringExpressions.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.withNewChildren(TreeNode.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$Lambda$1822/0x0000000100d21040.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$Lambda$61/0x00000001001d2040.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$Lambda$1822/0x0000000100d21040.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.BinaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.mapChildren(Expression.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$Lambda$1822/0x0000000100d21040.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnaryExpression.mapChildren(Expression.scala:467)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:486)
```

I tried many solutions including increasing driver and executor memory, using cache() and persist() for dataframe also doesn't worked for me.

I am using Spark 3.2.1
[Spark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTTy5.png)

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: First, try limiting your loops. Make it a for loop instead of a while and do only 1 or 2 iterations. See what is happening. Then do it with a few iterations. Using and re-using dataframes while joining them can create huge query plans that can result in cartesian products. You need to understand which steps create the bottleneck in order to solve that.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos thanks for the suggestion, the loop should iterate through all cases and assign every EMPLOYEE_ID an EMPLOYEE_LEVEL, I tried not to use any **action** function inside the loop to avoid the bottleneck but still when it's executing it gives the same error, I can't figure it out why? level_df has less records than content_df still it's giving error?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem. This error related to the mechanism of spark DAG, it use DAG lineage to track a series transformations, when the algorithms need to iterate, the lineage can grow fast and hit the limitation of memory. So break the lineage is necessary when implementing iteration algorithms.

There are mainly 2 ways: 1. add checkpoint. 2.recreate dataframe.
I modify my codes below, which just add a checkpoint to break the lineage and works for me.

```
epoch_cnt = 0
while True:
    print('hahaha1')
    
    print('cached df', len(spark.sparkContext._jsc.getPersistentRDDs().items()))
    
    singer_pairs_undirected_ungrouped = singer_pairs_undirected.join(old_song_group_kernel,
                                                                     on=singer_pairs_undirected['src'] == old_song_group_kernel['id'],
                                                                     how='left').filter(F.col('id').isNull()) \
        .select('src', 'dst')

    windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("src").orderBy(F.col("song_group_id_cnt").desc())

    singer_pairs_vote = singer_pairs_undirected_ungrouped.join(old_song_group_kernel,
                                                               on=singer_pairs_undirected_ungrouped['dst'] ==
                                                                  old_song_group_kernel['id'], how='inner') \
        .groupBy('src', 'song_group_id') \
        .agg(F.count('song_group_id').alias('song_group_id_cnt')) \
        .withColumn('song_group_id_cnt_rnk', F.row_number().over(windowSpec)) \
        .filter(F.col('song_group_id_cnt_rnk') == 1)

    singer_pairs_vote_output = singer_pairs_vote.select('src', 'song_group_id') \
        .withColumnRenamed('src', 'id')
    
    print('hahaha5')

    new_song_group_kernel = old_song_group_kernel.union(singer_pairs_vote_output) \
        .select('id', 'song_group_id').dropDuplicates().persist().checkpoint()
    
    print('hahaha9')
    
    current_kernel_cnt = new_song_group_kernel.count()
    
    print('hahaha2')
    old_song_group_kernel.unpersist()
    print('hahaha3')
    old_song_group_kernel = new_song_group_kernel

    epoch_cnt += 1
    print('epoch rounds: ', epoch_cnt)
    print('previous kernel count: ', previous_kernel_cnt)
    print('current kernel count: ', current_kernel_cnt)

    if current_kernel_cnt <= previous_kernel_cnt:
        print('Iteration done !')
        break
        
    print('hahaha4')

    previous_kernel_cnt = current_kernel_cnt
```